# how to delete an application in blacberry from another application

Tags: blackberry

I would like to know the method to delete an application in blackberry from another application running in the same phone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. It's inappropriate to be deleting applications on the users behalf. They can do this fine via an uninstaller.

Comment: -1 silky, what about a case of app+service+bunch of resources which don't fit .cod file size limitation? isn't it good to have a one installer _bb application_ to upload on device and which will install it all, register permissions and app data and unpack resources at once? and of course it's going to delete it all and reinstall in case of newer version. It would be too complicate for end user do this by his own using desktop manager.

Comment: should be handled by an installer.